# Drizzle not recognizing defined table

Tags: typescript, orm, bun, drizzle

I am just getting started using drizzle and created a simple table in a seperate schema file:

```
import { pgTable, serial, text, varchar } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";
 

export const users = pgTable('users', {
  id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
  email: text('email').unique(),
  password: varchar('password_hash', { length: 256 }),
});

export type User = typeof users.$inferSelect
export type NewUser = typeof users.$inferInsert
```

After that I am trying to generate the corresponding SQL files with:
`bunx drizzle-kit generate:pg --schema=src/db/schema/users.ts`

I do get the output: `0 tables No schema changes, nothing to migrate`

This is kinda odd because I just used the example code of the website and just tweaked the properties. I expect drizzle-kit to recognize the defined table called 'users'.
Am I missing something here?

Greetings :)

I also tried to rewrite the table definition with a schema definition like this:

```
import { pgSchema, serial, text, varchar } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";

export const mSchema = pgSchema("my_schema")

export const users = mSchema.table('users', {
id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
email: text('email').unique(),
password: varchar('password_hash', { length: 256 })
});
```

Still the same output: `0 tables No schema changes, nothing to migrate`

I will also add my config file, just in case it matters:

```json
{
  "driver": "pg",
  "schema": ["src/db/schema/users.ts"],
  "dbCredentials": {
    "connectionString": "postgres://localdev:localdev@localhost:5432/thesecondbrain"
  },
  "out": "./drizzle",
  "verbose": true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same issue - seems like `drizzle-kit` just doesn't work with bun at the moment. If you install npm alongside bun and specifically run the generate command with npm, it works just fine.

Comment: Update Feb 2024: Seems like `drizzle-kit` works with `bun` now - by using `bunx` (i.e `bunx drizzle-kit generate:sqlite --schema ./schema.ts`) https://bun.sh/guides/ecosystem/drizzle

Answer (score 1):

Install NodeJS and run it with the "npx" prefix , worked for me just now

Comment: That is the same thing as what the other answer said

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).